# Python wrong result joining lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm studying Python 3 and I'm blocked on an very simple exercise:
Having the string "Don't panic" convert it to "on tap" using the square brackets notation.
This is my code:

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
plist = list(phrase)
new_phrase = ''.join(plist[1:3]).join(plist[5:3:-1]).join(plist[-5:-7:-1])
print(new_phrase)
```

I expect to have in output the string "on tap"

```
''.join(plist[1:3])     //"on"
.join(plist[5:3:-1])    //" t"
.join(plist[-5:-7:-1])  //"ap"
```

but I have "a ontp" instead.
Why?!?
*NOTE: I know that there are other ways to solve this exercise, and I'm able to solve it in a different manner. I'm not looking for an alternative solution, I'm trying to understand what is wrong with the code that I wrote above.*

Comment: Do you really want to convert the string to a list, if you slice the string directly using `[]` notation, it's much, much simpler... seems like you're going out of your way to create work here...

Comment: Join doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It joins the elements of the iterable you pass as its argument, it places the string to the left of the dot between the elements. For instance ','.join('abc') will create this string: 'a,b,c'

Comment: I am getting a similar result for a simple [example](https://pastebin.com/pfCBzqPK). Maybe, it's because of the extra white spaces. **EDIT** @Q-life has explained it well, in the comments.

Comment: Yes, @Q-life is right, I thought that join was used to concatenate the strings not to 'merge' them.

Comment: I know you're not looking for solutions but just a pointer if you really want to use join: call join only once, pass the different slices as a list. ''.join([plist[1:3], plist[5:3:-1], plist[-5:-7:-1]])

Answer (score 3):

Simply add your elements instead of trying to join its content by their previous element.

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
plist = list(phrase)
new_phrase = ''.join(plist[1:3]) + ''.join(plist[5:3:-1]) + ''.join(plist[-5:-7:-1])
print(new_phrase) # -> on tap
```

Your code didn't work because you were joining `[" ", "t"]` and `["a", "p"]` by their previous elements:

```
                         "a ontp"
                           | - joined
           _________________________________
           |                                |
         " ont"                             |
           | - joined                       |
 _______________________                    |
 |                      |                   |
"on"                [" ", "t"]          ["a", "p"]
 |                      |                   |
''.join(plist[1:3]).join(plist[5:3:-1]).join(plist[-5:-7:-1])
```

Comment: If you concatenate the slices like that, why do you use the join function? Won't this yield the same result?: plist[1:3] + plist[5:3:-1] + plist[-5:-7:-1]

Answer (score 1):

Whatever comes before the `.join()` is interspaced in every element of what ever is inside the parenthesis:

```
'---'.join( "..." )  ==>  .---.---.
```

You are **chaining calls** of join - so every result is interspaced into the following join part:

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
plist = list(phrase)

np1 = ''.join(plist[1:3])          # with itermediate results, see output
np2 = np1.join(plist[5:3:-1])      #   the slice is "t ", it puts 'on' between " " and "t"
np3 = np2.join(plist[-5:-7:-1])    #   the slice is "ap", it puts " ont" between
                                   #   'a' and 'p' 

print(np1,np2,np3 )   # ('on', ' ont', 'a ontp')
```

Alternate solution:

```
print( phrase[1:3]+phrase[5:3:-1]+phrase[7:5:-1] )
```

Gives:

```
on tap
```

Answer (score 1):

Each successive join is utilizing what is in front to...well..join the elements with. This is why your code gives that result. as a recommendation, print the intermediates.

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
plist = list(phrase)
new_phrase = ''.join(plist[1:3]).join(plist[5:3:-1]).join(plist[-5:-7:-1])

print(''.join(plist[1:3])) #'on'
print(plist[5:3:-1]) #[' ','t']
print(''.join(plist[1:3]).join(plist[5:3:-1])) #' ont'
print(plist[-5:-7:-1]) #['a','p']
print(new_phrase) #a ontp
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more efficient if you created string slices

```
phrase = "Don't panic!"
new_pharse = phrase[1:3] + phrase[5:3:-1] + phrase[-5:-7:-1]
print(new_pharse)
```

Comment: But OP is not looking for alternatives: "*I'm trying to understand what is wrong with the code that I wrote above.*" It is in a note at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you take for example

```
something.join(somethingElse)
```

something will be the interspacing for somethingElse.
So in your code every time you use a join you are using what comes first as the interspacing for what are you joining. That's it.